# Database.Count Null Value

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, count

```
int userId;
int follow = 0;
if (Session["userId"] != null)
{
    userId = int.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString());
    follow = Model.Follow.Count(x => x.EdenUserId == userId);
}
```

> Error Code: Value cannot be null.

There exists some users who don't follow anybody so Count should be 0 but it returns null.

If user is following any user, table is populated without problem.

Can anyone please explain how can I count when there is a possibility that the lambda expression might return null?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int userId;
int follow = 0;
if (Session["userId"] != null)
{
    userId = int.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString());
    follow = Model.Follow.Count(x => x.EdenUserId == userId) == null? 0: Model.Follow.Count(x => x.EdenUserId == userId);
}
```